# Attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am running a laravel project in my local ubuntu 20.04 machine that was functioning fine in another machine. The project uses Image Magic to convert PDF to PNG. While I am evoking the function to convert PDF into PNG I get  the following error:

> ImagickException
> attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408

THE function looks:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $book = Book::all()->first();
        $file = public_path('' . $book->pdf);
        $count = 0;
        $im = new \Imagick($file);
        $blobList=[];
        do {
            $page = new \Imagick();
            $page->setResolution(300,300);
            $page->readImage($file . '['.$count.']');
            $page->setImageFormat("jpeg");
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            $image = $page->getImageBlob();
            array_push($blobList,$image);
            $count++;
        } while (5> $count);
//        $im->resizeImage(200,200,1,0);
        return view('notice/showbook', compact('book', 'blobList'));
    }
```

SO far I have installed image magic and gs and made changes in `policymap.xml` with reference to the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion)

Yet, the error persists. please help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I also faced same issue, when I tried to parse pdf using pyocr

```
wand.exceptions.PolicyError: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408
```

To solve this issue, I edit policy.xml of ImageMagick-6. In that file, change the policy rights to read/write

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

change to

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

If it doesn't solve your issue, you can also enable the below line in same file.

```
<!-- <policy domain="module" rights="none" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" /> -->
```

change to

```
<policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" />
```

Comment: Did you had to restart apache or some other service after this edit?

Comment: The policy file is located in /etc/ImageMagick-6 on UN*X sytems

Comment: @tedi yes. And / or, php if it is an run as an fpm service.

Comment: This is what I call falling over security..  Consider the wasted time and expense.  Being able to disable it temporarily (set to permissive? seems preferable.