# IMageMagick exception on PDF for Spatie Media Library

Tags: laravel, gd, ghostscript

I am using Spatie Media Library V7 and I am getting the following error when it attempts to perform a conversion

ImagickException: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408 in /var/www/html/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php:40

I have attepted the fixes from the following question without [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988719/attempt-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-policy-pdf-error)

I have GD and ghostscript all setup as well

my policy.xml is setup as follows:

```
  <policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS2" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS3" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
```

Any help will great be appreciated

Comment: Change all the policy rights for PS and PDF entries to "read|write".

Comment: @fmw42 this has already been applied as you can see from the above code snippet

Comment: Needs to be done for PS2, PS3, EPS, XPS. Also must be the policy location that Imagemagick is using - typically in /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-X (X=6 or 7). Also you must have Ghostscript installed as a delegate or program.

Comment: my policy file is only located in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml and I do have ghostscript installed. I have changed on the types that you have mentioned still the same issue

Comment: Are you on a shared server? If so, then only the hosting provider can make changes that relax the policy. You need to proper privileges to do so or they must do it.

Comment: I'm not on a shared server, I have full control of the server my policy file is now as follows

<policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS2" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS3" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="XPS" />

Comment: What is your exact version and platform?  What does `convert -version` show? (Or `magick -version` if on IM 7). What do you get from `convert -list format?`  Try adding the full path to `gs` (Ghostscript) in the delegates.xml file for the PDF/PS etc entries in the `DEVICE` field.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib

Comment: EPI  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Interchange format
      EPS  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript
     EPS2  PS2       -w-   Level II Encapsulated PostScript
     EPS3  PS3       -w+   Level III Encapsulated PostScript
PCT* PICT      rw-   Apple Macintosh QuickDraw/PICT

Comment: Here is what is the deletgates.xml file

<delegate decode="pdf" encode="ps" mode="bi" command="&quot;/usr/bin/gs&quot; -sstdout=%%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=ps2write&quot; -sPDFPassword=&quot;%a&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>

Comment: Your list of features do not include gs or gslib (for ghostscript). `Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib` So that makes me think that you might have it in your system, but not linked to Imagemagick.