# ImageMagick unable to convert PDF to images on WSL

Tags: imagemagick, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to use ImageMagick to convert a PDF to images, but I got this error:

> convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
>
> convert-im6.q16: no images defined `tmp/%03d.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.

I found a bunch of answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image)) that suggests to modify the policy.xml file; my problem is, I have no idea where to find that file on WSL: I tried looking for it in /etc/, with find and searching in Windows, to no avail. Any idea how to solve this issue on WLS?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it like this:

```
identify -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH
```

Failing that, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2836621%20policy.xml) search.

Failing that, use `find` in your WSL environment like this:

```
find / -name policy.xml 2> /dev/null
```

Failing that, just use Windows' Search to find a file called`policy.xml`